# Read text file and change it

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl by myself and I want to read from a text file and change a part of it. Suppose the text file I have looks like this and I want to increase the price by 10%:

```
Item     Price   
Jeans    50  
Blazer   100  
Suit     140
```

Here is the code I have written so far - I am a beginner so please be gentle:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;


open (IN,'Resources\shop.txt') or die "Can't open input file: $!";

open (OUT,">",'Resources\discount.txt') or die "Can't open output file: $!";


while (<IN>) {
    chomp;
    my @sections = split(/\t/);

    my $prices = ($sections[1]);                    
    $prices = (($prices)*1.1);                       
    print OUT "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: You left out your question... Please describe the problem, any errors you are getting, and what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: Wherever you are learning Perl, you should consider finding something more up to date. Global file handles like `IN` and `OUT` haven't been considered good practice for a long time now. And you should *always* use the three-argument form of `open`, like `open my $in_fh, '<', 'Resources\shop.txt' or die $!`

Comment: @BadtotheClone If that's TSV, you might want to use a module for it.

Comment: I'm ambivalent - tab sep parsing is easy with split - modules are useful if you have to handle quoting

Comment: @Biffen: I disagree. A tab-separated data file should never use quoted fields or escaped quotes within fields, and it is really awkward to get the module to process a simple character-separated file format. ***Always*** use `chomp` and `split /\t/` if you have a *proper* tab-separated file. If you don't then `Text::CSV` will fix nothing

Comment: @Biffen: Do you know of a module for tab-separated data? I can't find one, and it would be so simple as to be redundant

Comment: @Borodin Text::CSV can do TSV. And yes, manual splitting works too, but a module can have other advantages, e.g. understanding a header line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually alter `$_` at any point, so you're printing whatever you got in.

That `print` line should probably be:

```
print OUT join ("\t", $sections[0], $prices ),"\n";
```

Although actually, you should probably:

- Use lexical filehandles `open ( my $in, '<', 'Resources\shop.txt' );`
- I wouldn't actually `split` into an array, then assign that value, then change it - try `my @fields = split ( /\t/ ); $fields[1] *= 1.1; print OUT join "\t", @fields;`

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;


open( my $input, '<', 'Resources\shop.txt' )
    or die "Can't open input file: $!";
open( my $output, '>', 'Resources\discount.txt' )
    or die "Can't open output file: $!";

while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    my @sections = split(/\t/);
    $sections[1] *= 1.1 if $sections[1] =~ m/\d/;
    print {$output} join "\t", @sections, "\n";
}

close ( $input ) or warn $!;
close ( $output ) or warn $!;
```

Comment: Why use lexical filehandles ?

Comment: They're not global (imagine using a module, where someone else decided to use `OUT`). They get closed automatically on scope exit (when you use them within a sub.

Comment: You may want to add the `\n` to the end after the `join` in your extended example.

Comment: Another reason you should use lexical handles is that you can pass them around between subs, and never have to worry about clobbering a global somewhere far away. You can't do that with bareword handles. This is an extremely handy thing in many cases.

Comment: @123: *“Why use lexical file handles?”* should be a whole new separate question that I would be delighted to see! Please ask it

Comment: Also, theres a good reason not to use the old 2-arg open. If you mistype, or an input is not what you think, you could potentially overwrite the file you intend to read, and you'd be scratching your head. Always use 3-arg open with lexical handles, and trap any errors with `die` just like @Sobrique has shown. Note that as just a nit, the parens are unnecessary.

Comment: @stevieb: The primary reason for avoiding two-argument `open` calls is that it's tough to open a file called `>` or similar. That's not a problem on Windows, but is one of Unix's failings

Comment: @Sobrique: I wonder what you think about solutions like this, where you can post pretty much anything that will probably not be tested, followed by one or more intermediate updates, and then a final update that answers the question. It's certainly a way to get points

Comment: @Borodin... that's kind of what I was getting at, and should have given an example. For instance, if your filename var becomes `'>file.txt'` somehow, you're hosed.

Comment: @stevieb: Yes I got that. Thank you. But I'm talking specifically about solutions that look like `a = b` and the whole world goes *+1 wow yeah! a = b* and then the author updates his solution saying, *actually I meant that you should open the file in binary mode*. Sadly, the world then goes *+6 a = b and binary mode! hero!*

Answer (score 1):

for such a simple task as reading a text file and changing a part of it it is often better to use one-liners for inplace editing:

```
perl -ne '@s=split /\t/;if ($s[1]=~/^[\d.]+$/) {printf "$s[0]\t%f\n",$s[1]*1.1} else {print}' input_file.txt >output_file.txt
```

see `perl --help` and `perldoc perlrun` for -n, -i and -p switches

Comment: Could you expand on "better" please?  I have always assumes the opposite - one liners promote the kind of write only code that gives perl a bad name.

Comment: "often better" not means "always better", it depends on how often you need to do such things - if you just need quick and simple file correction  one or several times - I think using one-liner is a better approach